# How to edit the brand of Bootstrap navbar with WordPress menu

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have used the [WordPress-Bootstrap nav walker](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker) to create a Bootstrap navbar with a WordPress custom theme.

Here is the WordPress menu code:

```
<?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => 'primary',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'container'         => 'div',
            'container_class'   => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
             'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
        );
    ?>
```

What I want to do is to edit the 'brand' section of the bootstrap navbar, so that the source code output would include the below for the brand link on the navbar:

```
<a href="index.php"><img class="navbar-brand" src="logo.png"></a>
```

Currently it has the default Bootstrap 'brand' text. How do I edit this with the above WordPress code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very easy:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img class="logo" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
```

navbar-brand class is for the A element, not the link. Also, this element is outside teh navbar-walker. For example, to see it in context:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img class="logo" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
            </div>


            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'menu'              => 'primary',
                    'depth'             => 2,
                    'container'         => 'div',
                    'container_class'   => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
                    'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                    'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                    'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                );
            ?>
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
```

(note that this code is a fast example from a site I did, you can modify to your own needs since I don't know your entire code)

Comment: Silly me, didn't even realize it was not part of the navbar walker! Thanks.